# How to make a class track the last instance created?

Tags: python, class, object

This is a small code in which I have a planets class, and I want to know which was the last planet created.

```
class Planeta:
    ult=''

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ult = nombre #the last
        print(self.nombre, 'construido')

    def last(self):
        print('Ultimo constriuido:',self.ult) #print the last
```

So I create the planets

```
urano = Planeta('Urano')
neptuno = Planeta('Neptuno')
pluton = Planeta('pluton')
```

Then I want to know which was the last one created, so I call the method

```
urano.last()
```

But the output of the code is

```
Ultimo constriuido: Urano
```

When actually the last planet built is Pluto, I want the output to be

```
Ultimo constriuido: Pluton
```

I think I understand why this happens, I understand that if I command to call the `last()` method, the output is because at that moment that was the last.

But then how do I make the output as I want?

Comment: You could store the last planet in the class itself, e.g. `Planeta.ult = nombre`.

Comment: `last()` is an _instance method_, it only has information about it`self`, so in this case `urano.last` only has information about `urano`. What you need is a class variable (and maybe a classmethod) to track class instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__init__` method, you have not modified the `ult` you originally created. You have created an `ult` field on the instance `self`. Rather you need to manage `ult` as a field for the class itself.

Consider the below trivial example.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self, a):
...     self.a = a
...     Foo.last = a
...
>>> a = Foo("hello")
>>> a.a
'hello'
>>> b = Foo("world")
>>> b.a
'world'
>>> Foo.last
'world'
>>>
```

Or alternatively:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self, a):
...     self.a = a
...     self.__class__.last = a
...
>>> a = Foo("hello")
>>> b = Foo("world")
>>> Foo.last
'world'
>>>
```